# Restrict Auth & Session Cookies to a Subdomain in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a multi-tenanted application with several clients, who are distinguished by subdomain:

```
client1.mydomain.com
client2.mydomain.com
etc
```

I'm using forms authentication and the ASP.NET Auth & Session cookies on the client are set for the subdomain, e.g. client1.mydomain.com. This means that if I browse to client2.mydomain.com then I'm not logged in and the browser doesn't post the client1 cookies. Which is as it should be.

However something that has been picked up by our security testing is that you can take the cookie values from client1 and use the values to create cookies for client2 (we've done this in firebug). ASP.NET accepts these cookies and thinks you're authorised on client2.

How can I configure ASP.NET so that this doesn't happen?

The forms element in web.config allows you to set domain but I can't use this as I've a multi-tenanted app. I'm setting the cookie with

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

but I don't see a why to limit this to subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the domain name to the user data of the cookie. To do this you have to switch to another cookie api:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
   ... other parameters ..., domain );

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName );

cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt( ticket );

Response.SetCookie( cookie );
```

Then, in your global application class have an event handler that fires **after** the identity is established for the request. In the handler, verify that the domain name in the cookie is equal to a domain of the current request:

```
public void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
    HttpContext ctx = app.Context;

    if ( ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
    {
        // current domain
        string currentDomain = ctx.Request.Url.... // get the domain

        // domain from cookie
        FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)ctx.User.Identity;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

        string cookieDomain = ticket.UserData;

        if ( currentDomain != cookieDomain )
           throw new Exception( "break the execution of the current request" );

        ...
```

This check will validate if the cookie was issued for the current domain or rather someone tries to reuse cookies between different domains.